# What is the byte size of common Cassandra data types - To be used when calculating partition disk usage?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

I am trying to calculate the the partition size for each row in a table with arbitrary amount of columns and types using a formula from the Datastax Academy Data Modeling Course.

In order to do that I need to know the "size in bytes" for some common Cassandra data types. I tried to google this but I get a lot of suggestions so I am puzzled.

The data types I would like to know the byte size of are:

- A single Cassandra TEXT character (I googled answers from 2 - 4 bytes)
- A Cassandra DECIMAL
- A Cassandra INT (I suppose it is 4 bytes)
- A Cassandra BIGINT (I suppose it is 8 bytes)
- A Cassandra BOOELAN (I suppose it is 1 byte, .. or is it a single bit)

Any other considerations would of course also be appreciated regarding data types sizes in Cassandra.

Adding more info since it seems confusing to understand that I am only trying to estimate the "worst scenario disk usage" the data would occupy with out any compressions and other optimizations done by Cassandra behinds the scenes.

I am following the Datastax Academy Course DS220 (see link at end) and implement the formula and will use the info from answers here as variables in that formula.

https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling/physical-partition-size

Comment: By default, Cassandra compresses data on disk. So depending on the data you have, the type won't be very useful to evaluate real storage size. I think you should bench the size yourself.

Comment: Interesting answer not told by the Datastax Academy Course! What is the data compression ratio used by Cassandra (I am using C* 3.+), ... and the size of the types I'm asking for? Thanks!

Comment: The reason I am asking is because I have a use case to hint a user about the size of data they will put in a storage, including the "overhead" of wide rows.

Comment: some interesting comments about sizing data [here](http://datascale.io/sizing-cassandra-data/)

Comment: Thanks @LHWizard, this will definitely come in handy!

Comment: So you'd suggest me to always fill the tank up every day for going from home to office (10 miles) because I could go with the first gear instead on the fifth? You have optimizations, use them. Evaluate your (disk) overhead. Calculate your (memory) overheads.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think, from a pragmatic point of view, that it is wise to get a back-of-the-envelope estimate of worst case using the formulae in the ds220 course up-front at design time. The effect of compression often varies depending on algorithms and patterns in the data. From ds220 and http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html:

```
uuid: 16 bytes
timeuuid: 16 bytes
timestamp: 8 bytes
bigint: 8 bytes
counter: 8 bytes
double: 8 bytes
time: 8 bytes
inet: 4 bytes (IPv4) or 16 bytes (IPV6)
date: 4 bytes
float: 4 bytes
int 4 bytes
smallint: 2 bytes
tinyint: 1 byte
boolean: 1 byte (hopefully.. no source for this)
ascii: equires an estimate of average # chars * 1 byte/char
text/varchar: requires an estimate of average # chars * (avg. # bytes/char for language)
map/list/set/blob: an estimate
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to estimate the overhead associated to something is to actually perform *measures*. Really, you can't take the *single* data types and generalize something about them. If you have 4 `bigint`s columns and you're supposing that your overhead is X, if you have 400 `bigint` columns your overhead won't probably be 100x. That's because Cassandra compresses (by default, and it's a settings [tunable](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html#tabProp__moreCompression) per column family) everything before storing data on disk.

Try to load some data, I mean **production data**, in the cluster, and then let's know your results **and compression configuration**. You'd find some surprises.

Know your data.

Comment: All right, thanks! .. I suppose then that the Datastax Academy Course (see link) is just not right and they are teaching us stuff that is not true?

Comment: Can anyone at Datastax or deeply involved in Cassandra development confirm this?

Comment: You don't need any confirmation about that. Think about 1M bigints full of zeros. Would they take 8M bytes after compressing them or just a few bytes?

Comment: No, but if they where 1M of 64-bit figures then they would take a lot of space, remember I wrote "hint user". I know my data.

Comment: No, they *probably* wouldn't take a lot of space. That's very dependent on how your 64-bit values are correlated. Only random data cannot be compressed. The only way to discover that is to *try with real data*. So, if you know your data, why ask?

Comment: Lets end here, since it seems you don't know the answer of my initial question and that you refuse to understand that I want to know the "worst case disk usage".