# How to calculate size of data inserted in a Cassandra statement with Java driver

Tags: java, cassandra

I'd like to be able to calculate the storage size used for each of my Cassandra insert statements programmatically. Calculating the Java object size wouldn't be accurate as some of the fields such as partition key wouldn't take the same space due to Cassandra storage structure.

Has anyone come up with a way of calculating/estimating the size of that "data write"?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the byte size of common Cassandra data types - To be used when calculating partition disk usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087926/what-is-the-byte-size-of-common-cassandra-data-types-to-be-used-when-calculati)

Comment: Are you aware of Cassandra compressing data? You're looking for a very hard thing...